# IIS show message before serving page

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, web

I have an IIS website that is soon to be taken down. The website is just to serve files from a file share over HTTP. There are some HTML files etc on the share so it was created to let users share links which are all derived from this website.

However, it is now time for this website to go away. I'm looking to either display an `alert`, or a static `<div>` or a "*Message... You'll be redirected shortly*" for all requests that come to this website.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own IIS module. That will let you add HTML to all the served pages.
[IIS module and C#: how to modify the page content before sending it to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380400/iis-module-and-c-how-to-modify-the-page-content-before-sending-it-to-client)